# More economic and robust command for abstract at the beginning of chapters

Tags: chapters, abstract, amsbook

I want to put an abstract at the beginning of each chapter. I have cooked up a command in that aim, but it looks neither economic, nor robust (sometimes it is shifted to the right). How to improve this command?

My command is:

```
\def\chapstract#1{%
  \medskip%
  \begingroup%
    \itshape\small\noindent%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \leftskip=1em%
      \rightskip=1em% 
      #1%
    }%
  \endgroup%
  \medskip%
}
```

Comment: Never set `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` in LaTeX, they are TeX primitives which should always be set through a list environment such as `quote` (which is probably what you want here)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't give much indication of the desired layout but perhaps

```
\def\chapstract#1{\begin{quote}\small\itshape#1\end{quote}}
```

`\leftskip` and `\rightskip` are TeX primitives which should not be set directly in LaTeX. (The `quote` environment use the LaTeX list mechanism to set these in a safe way).

The full definition of `quote` in the standard classes is

```
 \newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

Which says to implicitly indent the left by a default amount and indent the right by the same as the left. So if as you note in comments that tou want a different indent then use `chapastractenv` instead of `quote` and define it as

```
\newenvironment{chapabstractenv}
               {\list{}{%
                  \small\itshape\setlength\leftmargin{3cm}%
                  \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

then if you want a command form rather than using an environment

```
   \def\chapstract#1{\begin{chapabstractenv}#1\end{chapabstractenv}}
```

Comment: In fact, I want smaller margins that in the quote environment.

Comment: @LionelDarondeau see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, I think I will modify the quotation environment like that:

```
\makeatletter 
\newenvironment{chapstract}{\list{}{ % 
\leftmargin1pc \listparindent\normalparindent 
\itemindent\z@ 
\rightmargin\leftmargin \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@}% 
\item[]% 
\itshape\small
}{% 
\endlist 
} 
\makeatother
```

It is not more economic but it seems to be more correct.