# Why should some TeX primitives never be set directly in LaTeX?

Tags: lists, primitives

In an earlier question [More economic and robust command for abstract at the beginning of chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169719/), David Carlisle told that one should never use directly some TeX primitives. How can I distinguish which primitives are safe to use?

Comment: Well, it depends on *what* primitive: `\hfill` is a TeX primitive, but it's surely allowed for use in LaTeX documents.

Comment: I assume you refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169719/more-economic-and-robust-command-for-abstract-at-the-beginning-of-chapters#comment390676_169719? Please focus the question on the specific primitives raised there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

well I didn't say any primitives, but those in particular (`\leftskip` and `\rightskip`) are bad ones to touch..

LaTeX list environments (which is almost all latex display environments, so not just `enumerate` but `center`, `verbatim`, `quote` etc) all need to know how much space is available on the line after current indentation levels are taken into account. LaTeX has several parameters that must be updated together, `\leftmargin`, `\linewidth`, `\@totalleftmargin`, `\textwidth`, `\hsize` are supposed to fit. If you change `\leftskip` without changing the entire LaTeX parameter structure then LaTeX won't "know" that you have indented stuff and all such environments will base their layout on the settings they think are in effect which may look OK or terrible depending on the exact circumstances, but if it looks OK it's by luck not design:-)

Comment: If I understand well your answer, if one uses a primitive modifying the layout of the page, then one has to modify accordingly all the parameters of the layout? And for this reason, but not because they are primitives, I should not use `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`?

Comment: As long as the environments you mention are not used, and the scope of the change to `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` is limited, there is thus no reason to restrain oneself: indeed the default `\l@section` and `\@dottedtocline` do not update neither `\leftmargin` nor `\linewidth` nor `\@totalleftmargin` nor `\textwidth` nor `\hsize`. I am pointing that out because many examples in the `etoc` manual manipulate `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` and `\parfillskip` to define the toc line styles, and people reading your answer might become very suspicious that this is dangerous.

Comment: @jfbu it is dangerous to play with fire but lots of people still like fireworks:-)

Comment: @LionelDarondeau yes all latex commands end up using the primitives eventually so clearly if you emulate enough of their definition it is equivalent to using the higher level commands, but it's like dropping to machine assembly code from a high level language, it might give you a slight efficiency gain, but it might just crash the system and either way it's a maintenance pain going forward.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle somehow, this is a comforting thought `:-)`